# Release apk react-native not load image

Tags: react-native

I coded an app using react-native. When I run debug all the images load, but when I run release then just some images are loaded.

I stored the images on Cloudinary and got the links to them from the API.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

link image not loaded: https://res.cloudinary.com/do-an-cnpm/image/upload/v1628150930/ces_qpzjg7.png

Link loaded: https://res.cloudinary.com/do-an-cnpm/image/upload/v1628150730/paradon_lltya5.png

I don't know why can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the differences between the images that load and the ones that don't? Can you share the URL's, sizes and formats?

Comment: @Saamer I just update image url

Comment: You put the link of the same image twice

Comment: @Saamer sorry I edited

Comment: If you aren't using it, then you should use this library instead for your images: https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image , And also, it seems like you have not implemented your pro guard file correctly, which is the only reason why it works in debug but not in production

Comment: it here https://github.com/namhihi237/JobApp/blob/main/src/components/companies/companies.js

Comment: Did you had any luck solving this issue? I'm having experiencing a very similar one when proguard(dexguard) is enabled but I cannot understand what could be the case from my logs as there are no errors/warnings regarding images